# Correctly loading a model to resume training (meta graph, ckpts)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm having trouble loading a model to **resume** training. 
I'm using a simple two-layered-NN (Fully connected) on a cifar data set for practice.

## NN Setup:

```
#full_connected_layers


import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


#input _-> hidden ->


def inference(data_samples, image_pixels, hidden_units, classes, reg_constant):

        with tf.variable_scope('Layer1'):
        # Define the variables
                weights = tf.get_variable(
                  name='weights',
                  shape=[image_pixels, hidden_units],
                  initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(
                    stddev=1.0 / np.sqrt(float(image_pixels))),
                  regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(reg_constant)
                )

                biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden_units]), name='biases')

                # Define the layer's output
                hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(data_samples, weights) + biases)


        with tf.variable_scope('Layer2'):
        # Define variables
                weights = tf.get_variable('weights', [hidden_units, classes],
                  initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(
                    stddev=1.0 / np.sqrt(float(hidden_units))),
                  regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(reg_constant))

                biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([classes]), name='biases')

        # Define the layer's output
                logits = tf.matmul(hidden, weights) + biases

        # Define summery-operation for 'logits'-variable
        tf.summary.histogram('logits', logits)



        return logits


def loss(logits, labels):
  '''Calculates the loss from logits and labels.

  Args:
    logits: Logits tensor, float - [batch size, number of classes].
    labels: Labels tensor, int64 - [batch size].

  Returns:
    loss: Loss tensor of type float.
  '''

  with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
    # Operation to determine the cross entropy between logits and labels
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
      tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        logits=logits, labels=labels, name='cross_entropy'))

    # Operation for the loss function
    loss = cross_entropy + tf.add_n(tf.get_collection(
      tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES))

    # Add a scalar summary for the loss
    tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

  return loss




def training(loss, learning_rate):


  # Create a variable to track the global step
  global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)


  train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(
    loss, global_step=global_step)

  #train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate, beta1, beta2, epsilon).minimize(
    #loss, global_step=global_step)


  return train_step




def evaluation(logits, labels):


  with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
    # Operation comparing prediction with true label
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits,1), labels)

    # Operation calculating the accuracy of the predictions
    accuracy =  tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    # Summary operation for the accuracy
    tf.summary.scalar('train_accuracy', accuracy)

  return accuracy
```

### Saved model like this:

```
if (i + 1) % 500 == 0:
      saver.save(sess, MODEL_DIR, global_step=i)  
      print('Saved checkpoint')
```

### Saved model files

Within this directory: 
`C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\CIFAR - PROJECT\parameters_no_changes`

I have the following files as well as `model.ckpt-499.index` etc:

```
model.ckpt-999.meta
model.ckpt-999.index
model.ckpt-999.data-00000-of-00001
```

### My attempt at loading the model

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import time
from datetime import datetime
import os
import data_helpers
import full_connected_layers
import itertools


learning_rate = .0001
max_steps = 3000
batch_size = 400

checkpoint = r'C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\CIFAR - PROJECT\parameters_no_changes\model.ckpt-999'





with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(r'C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\CIFAR - PROJECT' +
                                    '\\parameters_no_changes\model.ckpt-999.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, checkpoint)


data_sets = data_helpers.load_data()

images = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('images:0') #image placeholder
labels = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image-labels:0') #placeholder
loss = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('Loss/add:0')
#global_step = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('global_step/initial_value_1:0')

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(
    loss)



accuracy = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('Accuracy/Mean:0')




with tf.Session() as sess:

  #sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  zipped_data = zip(data_sets['images_train'], data_sets['labels_train'])
  batches = data_helpers.gen_batch(list(zipped_data), batch_size,
    max_steps)



  for i in range(max_steps):

    # Get next input data batch
    batch = next(batches)
    images_batch, labels_batch = zip(*batch)
    feed_dict = {
      images: images_batch,
      labels: labels_batch

       }

    if i % 100 == 0:
      train_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict=feed_dict)
      print('Step {:d}, training accuracy {:g}'.format(i, train_accuracy))




    ts,loss_  =sess.run([train_step, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

### Errors and confusion

1) Should I be using this command `latest_checkpoint` to restore:
`

```
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))`
```

I see some tutorials that just point to the folder holding the 
.data, .index files.

2) Which brings me to the second question:  What should I be using as the second parameter of `saver.restore`.
Currently I'm just pointing to the **folder/dir** that holds those files

3) I'm not purposely initializing any variables as I was told, that would overwrite the stored weight and bias values. This seems to be leading to this error:

`FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value Layer1/weights
     [[Node: Layer1/weights/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Layer1/weights"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Layer1/weights)]]`

4) However, If I do initialize all variables via this code:

`sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`

My model seems to start training from scratch (and not resuming training)

Does that mean I'm supposed to load all weights and biases via 
`get_tensor` explicitly? If so , how I deal with layers with 20 plus layers?

5) When I run this command

```
for i in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations():
    print(i.values)
```

I see many global_steps tensors/operations,

```
'global_step/initial_value' type=Const>>
'global_step' type=VariableV2>>
<'global_step/Assign' type=Assign>>

global_step/read' type=Identity>>
```

I was trying to load this variable into my current graph, but
didn't know which one I'm supposed to `get` using the command 
get_tensor_by_name. Most of them were resulting in a does not exist error.

6) Same with `loss` which loss am I supposed to load into my graph with `get_tensor`

These are the options:

```
<bound method Operation.values of <tf.Operation 'Loss/Const' type=Const>>
<bound method Operation.values of <tf.Operation 'Loss/Mean' type=Mean>>
<bound method Operation.values of <tf.Operation 'Loss/AddN' type=AddN>>
<bound method Operation.values of <tf.Operation 'Loss/add' type=Add>>
<bound method Operation.values of <tf.Operation 'Loss/loss/tags' type=Const>>
<bound method Operation.values of <tf.Operation 'Loss/loss' type=ScalarSummary>>
```

6) Lastly, I see a lot of gradient operations when I look at all
the nodes of the graph but I don't see any nodes related to `train_step` (the
python variable I created that points to the Gradient Dsecent Optimizer). Does that mean I don't need to load it into this graph via `get_tensor`?

Thank  you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ In the folder where you save your checkpoint, there should be a file named 'checkpoint' which contains the name of your latest checkpoint.
I normally read this file to find latest checkpoint.

2/ I use checkpoint_directory/global_step.
With this, tf will create 4 files in the checkpoint_directory:

> global_step.data-00000-of-00001
>   global_step.index
>   global_step.meta
>   checkpoint

3/ 4/ I'm pretty sure you don't need to pre-initialize the graph before loading, at least I don't do it.
There is some difference: instead of import_meta_graph, I rebuild the whole graph every time I load, but I'm sure it's not an issue to load before you initialize.

5/ Be careful not to mis-take operations for tensors and you are good to go. Tensor name should be op_name:0, which mean this tensor is the output[0] of the operation op_name.

6/ 7/ Well, let me just tell you how I resume my checkpoint. This is probably not the correct way, but it really saves me from the burden of get_tensor_by_name. Seriously get_tensor_by_name can be a real pita sometimes.
Normally my loading process will go through: rebuild graph, load checkpoint, create some new tensors if needed, initialize tensors that is not in the checkpoint.

> build_net() 
>   saver = tf.train.Saver()
>   saver.restore(session, checkpoint_dir/global_step)
>   add_loss_and_optimizer()
>   initialize_all_uninitialized_tensor

checkpoint_dir/global_step is from the checkpoint file if you want the latest checkpoint, or you can use different global_step to get the specific checkpoint that you wanna load.

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful.

Comment: hi, could you explain how to add optimizer and initialize_uninitialized_tensor(such as states in new-added Adam/Adagrad optimizer)? I was just stuck in FailedPreconditionError... Reusing AdamOptimizer in checkpoint and adding new AdamOptimizer both stopped at intialize error.

Comment: @futureer Well this may be a bit too late.

`uninitialized_vars = [var for var in all_var if not sess.run(tf.is_variable_initialized(var))]`
`sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(var_list=uninitialized_vars))`

Answer (score 6):

I usually did this sequence of operations:

1. Initialize
2. Restore

This translates to this kind of code:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
    ...
```

It will avoid the non-initialized error, and the restore will overwrite with the values from the checkpoint.

Comment: Ah! You are correct. Going to do some more testing with global_steps. Thank you so much.